# Error testing Polymer Dart components

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-polymer, dart-pub

I'm having trouble getting any of my Polymer Dart tests to run due to the following error that appears after I run `pub run test --pub-serve=8081 -p chrome`

00:18 +1 -2: compiling test\markdone_test.dart
  Failed to load "test\markdone_test.dart": Reflecting on type 'TodoInput' without capability
  dart:_internal  wrapException

TodoInput is one of the Polymer Dart components for this project, but I've gotten the same error on other projects I have tried testing.

I have followed the documentation on the pub package for dart-lang/test:

1. Added listorder_test.dart and listorder_test.html with x-dart-test referencing my dart file
2. Added an entrypoint under the polymer transformer for test/listorder_test.html
3. Added the test/pub_serve transformer with $include: test/**_test{.*,}.dart

Am I missing some setup step or annotation/metadata?  I've been over the docs for testing and they really only have the one mention of testing Polymer components without much else.

Comment: What version of reflectable is listed in your `pubspec.lock`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer 0.5.3

Comment: I would create a bug report in the Dart Polymer repo. I think you followed the instructons. I assume you call `await initPolymer()` at top of main?

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I do in my main function.

Comment: See also https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart/issues/690